# Stencil image appearing extremely low resolution

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

[image]

Stencil image appearing extremely low resolution. The original image is 16000 px... why is the resolution so low when painting a stencil image ?

Comment: What is the resolution of the canvas you are painting into? The stencil image is 16000 pixels, but if the target is low then there aren't enough pixels to interpret the stencil image.

Comment: It is not the problem with the canvas...the canvas size is 8000 px...the stencil even in the viewport looks like its size is around a 200px image...

Comment: Can you try to use the Clone tool option in the 2d editor, and see if you get the same pixelation there?

Answer (score 4):

Stencil has to be a power of 2 image, with dimensions of
8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024px, etc in width or height (512x512, 1024x1024,
2048x2048 or 1024x512, 2048x1024 or 512x1024, 1024x2048, 1024x128, 128x4096 - and so on, as long as it can be doubled or halved by 2) that way Blender will display it correctly. It's a general rule for any 3D texture, actually.

I know it's an old question, but a lot of people asked me about this lately and they found no direct answers online. So I figured you can never be too late with an answer. :)

Comment: what about size like 2436 x 3352  it can be doubled or halved by 2 but it pixelated for me (my old question with the same issue https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278628/texture-becomes-very-pixelated-in-the-viewport  - it have different resolution but the same problem)