# texture becomes very pixelated in the viewport

Tags: texture-painting

I have an image that I use as a brush texture. Its resolution is about 8k. The problem is that when I load it, it becomes pixelated in the viewport (there are no problems when drawing on the model). However, what bothers me is that it becomes very pixelated in the viewport, and because of this, it is more difficult for me to work with it. I'm using Stencil mapping to put texture as projection
Please tell me how to fix this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your [.blend](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/53513) file?

Comment: Sorry, I can't, I have NDA. But I use the usual steps 
1) add an image (brush-settings-open) 
2) in tool settings -texture-mapping Stencil.
And the image that I upload as the basis for the projection is loaded very pixelated (it is projected onto the model in the original 8k quality), but in the viewport it is displayed pixelated. I've been looking for viewport quality settings for brush texture  but can't find it.

Comment: What happens if you go the the *Image Properties Panel > Settings* and check *View as Render*?

Comment: Nothing, I've added screenshot with my settings

Comment: Have you set Limit size in viewport settings?

Comment: no I have it set to off/anisotropic 16/display method automatic(when changing for glsl/2d doesn't help)